Provisioning issue using "/api/v1/provisioning/alert-rules/:uid/export" endpoint
I started using Grafana API for creating new alerts and I start to lose it...
My goal:

GET JSON of already existing alert created via UI
Modify alert query/name whatever
POST modified JSON to Grafana

Results of using "/api/v1/provisioning/alert-rules/:uid/export " endpoint
According to the Grafna documentation, I need to use the /api/v1/provisioning/alert-rules/:uid/export  endpoint to get the JSON appropriate for provisioning.
But whenever I get this JSON and edit only the 'title' and 'uid' ('I set 'uid' to null). then I POST this modifed JSON via API and I recive
Error : 400, ErrorMessage: {"message":"invalid alert rule: no queries or expressions are found","traceID":""}  
But I didn't even edit the query or expressions, I only edited the title and I set the alert uid to null for example.
Documentation: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/alerting/set-up/provision-alerting-resources/export-alerting-resources/
JSON I get from the /export endpoint
{
"apiVersion": 1,
"groups": [
    {
        "orgId": 1,
        "name": "1min",
        "folder": "test",
        "interval": "1m",
        "rules": [
            {
                "uid": "xxx",
                "title": "tester",
                "condition": "C",
                "data": [
                    {
                        "refId": "A",
                        "relativeTimeRange": {
                            "from": 600,
                            "to": 0
                        },
                        "datasourceUid": "xxxxx",
                        "model": {
                            "datasource": {
                                "type": "influxdb",
                                "uid": "xxxx"
                            },
                            "groupBy": [
                                {
                                    "params": [
                                        "$__interval"
                                    ],
                                    "type": "time"
                                },
                                {
                                    "params": [
                                        "null"
                                    ],
                                    "type": "fill"
                                }
                            ],
                            "intervalMs": 1000,
                            "maxDataPoints": 43200,
                            "measurement": "Amount",
                            "orderByTime": "ASC",
                            "policy": "default",
                            "query": "SELECT count(\"value\") FROM \"Amount_counter\" WHERE (\"currency\"::tag = 'BIT') AND $timeFilter GROUP BY time($__interval) fill(null)",
                            "rawQuery": true,
                            "refId": "A",
                            "resultFormat": "time_series",
                            "select": [
                                [
                                    {
                                        "params": [
                                            "value"
                                        ],
                                        "type": "field"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "params": [],
                                        "type": "count"
                                    }
                                ]
                            ],
                            "tags": [
                                {
                                    "key": "currency::tag",
                                    "operator": "=",
                                    "value": "BIT"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "refId": "B",
                        "relativeTimeRange": {
                            "from": 600,
                            "to": 0
                        },
                        "datasourceUid": "__expr__",
                        "model": {
                            "conditions": [
                                {
                                    "evaluator": {
                                        "params": [],
                                        "type": "gt"
                                    },
                                    "operator": {
                                        "type": "and"
                                    },
                                    "query": {
                                        "params": [
                                            "B"
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    "reducer": {
                                        "params": [],
                                        "type": "last"
                                    },
                                    "type": "query"
                                }
                            ],
                            "datasource": {
                                "type": "__expr__",
                                "uid": "__expr__"
                            },
                            "expression": "A",
                            "intervalMs": 1000,
                            "maxDataPoints": 43200,
                            "reducer": "sum",
                            "refId": "B",
                            "settings": {
                                "mode": "dropNN"
                            },
                            "type": "reduce"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "refId": "C",
                        "relativeTimeRange": {
                            "from": 600,
                            "to": 0
                        },
                        "datasourceUid": "__expr__",
                        "model": {
                            "conditions": [
                                {
                                    "evaluator": {
                                        "params": [
                                            5
                                        ],
                                        "type": "gt"
                                    },
                                    "operator": {
                                        "type": "and"
                                    },
                                    "query": {
                                        "params": [
                                            "C"
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    "reducer": {
                                        "params": [],
                                        "type": "last"
                                    },
                                    "type": "query"
                                }
                            ],
                            "datasource": {
                                "type": "__expr__",
                                "uid": "__expr__"
                            },
                            "expression": "B",
                            "intervalMs": 1000,
                            "maxDataPoints": 43200,
                            "refId": "C",
                            "type": "threshold"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "noDataState": "NoData",
                "execErrState": "Error",
                "for": "5m",
                "labels": {
                    "owner": "me",
                    "severity": "warning"
                },
                "isPaused": false
            }
        ]
    }
]

}
Results of using "/api/v1/provisioning/alert-rules/:uid"
I started downloading JSON via endpoint/api/v1/provisioning/alert-rules/:uid but according to the documentation "Note that the JSON format from most of the following endpoints is not fully compatible with provisioning via configuration JSON files." But guess what... I downoland it from the endpoint, I edit the title and query, set up 'id' and 'uid' to 'null' (so it can be automaticly assigned for new alert) and it worked.
Documentation: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/developers/http_api/alerting_provisioning/
My Question
I don't understand why this is happening, it should work the other way around. Can someone explain to me why I am getting an "Error" when trying to send JSON which should be suitable for provisioning?
